# Xcode 4.3.2 "Invalid Icon" for iPad Retina Display

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, icons, retina-display

I am trying in vain to add an iPad retina icon to multiple XCode 4.3.2 projects.

I correctly resize the image in an external program to 114x144 pixels, then I drag it into the "iPad Deployment Info" section of the  "Summary" window in my project.
An error message pops up to say that the icon size is invalid (see image) :

[image: invalid image xcode 4.3.2]

*The file "/Users/max/Desktop/General Images/Camera/icns/114.png" does not match the required size. It must be 144 x 144 pixels in size.*

I am absolutely certain that it IS the correct size, and seeing as I used to be able to simply drag-and-drop, and because it is happening in multiple projects, if this is a bug in XCode?

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: 114 pixels are for iPhone retina; 144 pixels are for iPad retina.

Comment: Try to look with more attention before run and ask in StackOverflow. ;-) Just a tip.

Comment: I +1'd this question as this is an honest mistake that any iOS dev could make (and I appreciate Query's attempt to provide detail with an explanatory graphic).  There's a difference in sizes between iPhone & iPad icons and also between non-Retina and Retina versions.  Apple needs to come up with a better standard (e.g. one large icon graphic file that gets shrunk down to what's appropriate for the device & display type).

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent so long trying to figure out what went wrong! Sometimes numbers get a bit mixed up in my head....

Comment: +1 - I just did the same thing as the OP! Mistook 114 for 144!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure naming convention with proper size should be followed

`Normal Display-icon.png(57*57)`

`Retina Display=icon@2x.png(114*114)`

I hope this would work.